# Turn multiple rows of events with timestamps in a dataframe to single row with start and end datetime

Tags: python, apache-spark, pyspark

I have rows for a single device and I would like to group all the same events that happen in sequence.

I am also would like to do this with pyspark

So given the following:

```
+--------------------+-------+
|      datetime      | event |
+--------------------+-------+
| 12-02-18T08:20:00  |     1 |
| 12-02-18T08:25:00  |     1 |
| 12-02-18T08:30:00  |     1 |
| 12-02-18T09:00:00  |     2 |
| 12-02-18T09:05:00  |     2 |
| 12-02-18T09:10:00  |     1 |
| 12-02-18T09:15:00  |     1 |
+--------------------+-------+
```

I would like to end up with the following:

```
+-------------------+-------------------+-------+
|    start_time     |     end_time      | event |
+-------------------+-------------------+-------+
| 12-02-18T08:20:00 | 12-02-18T09:00:00 |     1 |
| 12-02-18T09:00:00 | 12-02-18T09:10:00 |     2 |
| 12-02-18T09:10:00 | null              |     1 |
+-------------------+-------------------+-------+
```

There will be no overlapping events so does not need to be considered. I taught of doing this with a UDF but was wondering if anyone knew of a more elegant/efficient way.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

With approach provided by Florian (Window function), can be done by taking rows with changed events, and then take next changed date, on Scala:

```
val df = List(
  ("12-02-18T08:20:00", 1),
  ("12-02-18T08:25:00", 1),
  ("12-02-18T08:30:00", 1),
  ("12-02-18T09:00:00", 2),
  ("12-02-18T09:05:00", 2),
  ("12-02-18T09:10:00", 1),
  ("12-02-18T09:15:00", 1)
).toDF("datetime", "event")
df.show(false)

val w = Window.orderBy("datetime")
val changedRowsOnlyDF = df.withColumn("changed", $"event" =!= lag($"event", 1, 0).over(w))
  .where($"changed")

val result = changedRowsOnlyDF
  .withColumn("end_time", lead($"datetime", 1).over(w))
  .drop("changed")
  .withColumnRenamed("datetime", "start_time")
result.show(false)
```

Output:

```
+-----------------+-----+-----------------+
|start_time       |event|end_time         |
+-----------------+-----+-----------------+
|12-02-18T08:20:00|1    |12-02-18T09:00:00|
|12-02-18T09:00:00|2    |12-02-18T09:10:00|
|12-02-18T09:10:00|1    |null             |
+-----------------+-----+-----------------+
```

**Disclaimers**: such approach can be used for small volumes of data, Spark notified by message:

> WARN org.apache.spark.sql.execution.window.WindowExec: No Partition Defined for Window operation! Moving all data to a single partition, this can cause serious performance degradation.

Answer (score 2):

Instead of using a `UDF`, you could use `Window` to find transitions in events and create a new column from that to use in grouping (see [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47014555/partition-pyspark-dataframe-based-on-the-change-in-column-value)). Then we can aggregate to find the minimum and the maximum times per event. A working example is given below, hope this helps!

```
import pyspark.sql.functions as F
from pyspark.sql import Window

# SAMPLE DATA
df = spark.sparkContext.parallelize([
    ('2018-07-20T01:00:00.000Z','1'),
    ('2018-07-20T02:00:00.000Z','1'),
    ('2018-07-20T03:00:00.000Z','2'),
    ('2018-07-20T04:00:00.000Z','2'),
    ('2018-07-20T05:00:00.000Z','1')
]).toDF(("datetime","event" ))

# CALCULATE START AND END TIMES
w = Window.orderBy('datetime')
df_result = (df
    .withColumn("changed", (F.col('event') != F.lag('event', 1, 0).over(w)).cast('int'))
    .withColumn("group_id", F.sum("changed").over(w)).drop("changed")
    .groupBy('group_id','event').agg(
    F.min('datetime').alias('start'),
    F.max('datetime').alias('end'))
    .drop('group_id'))

df_result.show()
```

Output:

```
+-----+--------------------+--------------------+
|event|               start|                 end|
+-----+--------------------+--------------------+
|    1|2018-07-20T01:00:...|2018-07-20T02:00:...|
|    2|2018-07-20T03:00:...|2018-07-20T04:00:...|
|    1|2018-07-20T05:00:...|2018-07-20T05:00:...|
+-----+--------------------+--------------------+
```

Comment: Tested and approved. I find clever using F.sum("changed"), I would have used two conditions to search for changes from event 1 towards 2 or vice versa. But yours seems better